# VS2012 C++ Runtime library does not appear in Publish Prerequisites

Tags: visual-c++, deployment, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, publish

I am using ClickOnce to deploy a C# application with a reference to a C++ project, using VS2012 on Windows 7.

In VS2010, I was able to VC++ 2010 runtime library as one of the prerequisites, however in VS2012, there is no such equivalent.

When running the deployed app on a non-developer machine, I receive an error that the C++ project could not be loaded.

I installed the VC++ 2012 redistributables from 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 but I still don't see this option in the prerequisites.

When I browse to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\
there is a package.xml that says:
You do not have the permissions required to install Visual C++ 2012 Runtime Libraries (x86).

Which makes no sense because I am an Admin on this computer.

Has anyone been able to deploy a .NET project in 2012 with a reference to a C++ project?

Comment: Hehe, that's an error message that's defined in the package.xml, displayed when the user is not an admin.  The option is missing because the DLLs are copied to the Windows directory.  Not permitted in ClickOnce.  You'll need local deployment or a regular setup program or ask the user to take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you specify where exactly in the Windows folder are the DLLs and what DLLs should I be looking for? Did you find documentation on why this is the case?